# mysql views performance when subset of the view's fields are required

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I want to create a database view which has some costly fields to compute. I'm trying to see what is the cost if the costly fields are not required. However, I see that this is not the case, and that the cost is the same.

As toy example, I have a table with users information. I have a view on this table that returns the id,name and the number of users whose name are like mine.

```
create view same_name as 
select  
       id,
       name,
       (select count(*) from users as u2 where u2.name = u1.name) as same_name_count,
       from users as u1;
```

I'm now doing two queries over the table. In the first one I'm select all fields, in the second one I'm just selecting single field (the name). In both I constrain over the id.

```
mysql> select * from same_name where id = 2;
+----+--------+-----------------+
| id | name   | same_name_count |
+----+--------+-----------------+
|  2 | meidan |             125 |
+----+--------+-----------------+
1 row in set (12.15 sec)

mysql> select name from same_name where id = 2;
+--------+
| name   |
+--------+
| meidan |
+--------+
1 row in set (12.15 sec)
```

So it can be seen that the performance is the same and that no optimization is done here on the missing field. Is this the expected behavior? Any hints on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most of CPU cycles are wasted on selections of rows and calculations (which are the same in both cases), not data transfer itself. If each of your table's rows does not occupy several kilobytes of data as opposed to several bytes in `name` field, you won't see much of a difference on fast network connection.

Comment: I understand that, the question was why it wastes the cpu cycles on computing the same_name_count if this field is not required. thanks.

Comment: @eran You are asking too much from freeware RDBMS. I don't think, that even commercial RDBMSes like Oracle and MSSQL use such optimisations. You request a subset from predefined query (view), so, that query is fetched into buffer and then subset is selected.  Calculation will take place anyway.